# How to process files inside sub folders but not from folders inside sub folder

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have developed an SSIS package which will load the excel files to SQLSERVER database. The package is working fine. But I need to modify the package with the below requirements.

Main Folder Name : “ROOT”
Sub Folders: “A” , “B”, ”C”
Folders inside Every Sub folder : “Processed”,
 “ Invalid”
and new excel files that have to be processed whenever the package runs.

Now I need to process the files inside every sub folder “A”, “B” & “C” but not the files inside the folders “Processed” and “Invalid”

This is because once I processed the file, package will move that file to “Processed” folder and if it fails to process particular excel file package will move the file to “Invalid” folder.

So, the folders “processed” and “Invalid” inside every subfolder contains only Old files. I tried using two foreach loops…but failed and it’s a big confusion for me. If i enable "traverse sub-folders option in foreach loop, it is processing the already processed files also.
Please someone help me on this[image: Folders Hierarchy]

Comment: Can you post more details about how you attempted using two foreach loops?    Seems like that would be the way to go.   Why did your attempt fail?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a script task to populate the folders in a variable and a ForEach loop that returns the foldername from the array the script task populates.

Here is a method:

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/foreach-folder-enumerator.html

Inside that ForEach you'll need to add another ForEach file loop and the rest of your components.  Note that the method I linked has two options for the script task, the first one will only give you the children of the parent folder which is what you appear to be asking for, but the second one traverses all subfolders so you would need to filter out the subfolders you don't want if you used that script.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a source script component

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo root = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\");

foreach (var subDir in root.GetDirectories())
{
    foreach (var item in subDir.GetFiles("*.csv"))
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.FileName = item.FullName;
    }
}
Output0Buffer.EndOfRowset();
```